# Import picture in gallery PIMCORE

Tags: csv, prestashop, gallery, pimcore

I am using a PIMCORE version 6.5, and I would like to import product images via csv.

But the class of my product is of type "gallery" and not simple images.

When I export a test to CSV it gives me a serialized code to encrypt in Base64.

My question is that I only have the local path of my photos, and I would like to import them into my gallery. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various solutions to this problem. What I would do is to write a little PHP Script (e.g. in a controller or a service) for the import.

1) Copy all your local images into some asset folder path within your Pimcore project

2) Create the assets via the PHP API: https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Assets/Working_with_PHP_API.html

3) Create/update the galleries via the PHP API: https://pimcore.com/docs/6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Image_Types.html

Not sure why you need a .csv for this import but if you have important information or metadata there just upload it in the controller and use the information within the script in order to create the correct objects.

Comment: Do you have a small example, because that's what I've been testing for several days, but without success. I can't initialize my product object and then assign something to it.

Comment: First of all you need the Asset objects. Is this part working?

Comment: use \Pimcore\Model\DataObject;

include __DIR__ . "/../vendor/autoload.php";
$product = Pimcore\Model\DataObject::getByid(3827); => Error : atal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getContainer() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Pimcore.php:204

Comment: Why do you include vendor/autoload.php manually? Just create an ImportController (and maybe a Service additionally) and the container will be there. Everything else you need can be passed by dependency injection?